# Hide divs when another div is expanded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 8 divs on my page. 4 at the top and 4 at the bottom. For the 4 divs at the top I have a piece of Javascript code that expands/unhides a div below them (see JSFiddle). I would like to make it so that when these divs are expanded the 4 divs at the bottom of the page hide. Then, when the div is unexpanded, the 4 divs at the bottom of the page show again.

Please see my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/44478c41/

I don't have much knowledge of Javascript but I had a fiddle around with my existing code to try and get it to work, I managed to hide the div but not the content within the div, nor was I able to get it to unhide again. Here is what I edited my code to:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var $cont;    
    function tgl_conts(){
        $('.static').stop().animate({height: 0},1200);
        $cont.stop().animate({height:210},1200);
    }

    $('.tab_collapsable').on('click',function(){
        var tabClass=$(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
        $cont = $('.'+tabClass+':not(.tab_collapsable)');
        var h = ($cont.height() === 0) ? tgl_conts() :  ( $cont.stop().animate({height: 0},1200) );  
    });

    });
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: make a jsfiddle please

Comment: I already posted a JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/44478c41/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another solution:

```
$('.tab_collapsable').on('click',function(){
    var tabClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
    var h = $('.content.'+tabClass).height() ? 0 : 210;

    $('.content').stop().animate({height: h},1200)
    .not('.'+tabClass).stop().animate({height: 0},1200);

    $('.static').stop().animate({height: h ? 0 : 250},1200);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4qr3hz4s/)

Comment: Thanks, but although it hides the bottom divs, the content within them still seems to show?

Comment: @Tom , what *content* ? Do you have the same content for bottom boxes like in top boxes? I wrote this code for the HTML in your fiddle :-)

Comment: Sorry, you won't be able to see it in that example because of the fact the background image doesn't show. Here take a look in this updated example - https://jsfiddle.net/4qr3hz4s/1/ - The text within the divs still shows after the divs have hidden.

Comment: You could use f.ex `opacity` instead of `height` - https://jsfiddle.net/j55uLvd5/  , or change `display` CSS property on animation complete - https://jsfiddle.net/8yzoh87j/

Comment: I can't really find where the issue came from. I'll try to find it out

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, you can either check the visibility of content divs or just track open/close via a flag

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44478c41/8/)

Handling via flag;

```
var bottomDivOpen=true;
function showHideBottomDiv(){
            if(bottomDivOpen==true){
                $(".static").hide();
                bottomDivOpen=false;
            }else{
                $(".static").show();
                bottomDivOpen=true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is a good practice but when you click another tab the bottom divs reappear. Reacts like a toggle.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to retain animation effect on static divs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var $cont;    
        function tgl_conts(){
            $('.content').stop().animate({height: 0},1200);
            $cont.stop().animate({height:210},1200);
        }

        $('.tab_collapsable').on('click',function(){
            var tabClass=$(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
            $cont = $('.'+tabClass+':not(.tab_collapsable)');
            if ($cont.height() === 0) {
                tgl_conts();
                $('.static').stop().animate({height: 0},1200);
                } else {
                $cont.stop().animate({height: 0},1200);
                 $('.static').stop().animate({height: 250},1200);
                }


        });



        });
```

Comment: It won't work if the animation is not complete (for example - click quickly on boxes 1,2,1)